# ¿Por qué no se produce un null pointer si le paso el objeto como referencia?

Tags: java

Estoy preparándome el certificado OCA java 8 y me ha surgido la siguiente duda con este bloque de código:

```
package ejemplo;
    public class Exam {

    private String name;
    
    private Exam other;

    public Exam(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setOther(Exam other) {
        this.other = other;
    }
    
    public Exam getOther() {
        return other;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
}
```

```
package ejemplo;
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exam php = new Exam("PHP");
        Exam java = new Exam("Java");
        
        java.setOther(php);
        System.out.println(php);
        php = null;
        System.out.println(java.getOther());
    }
}
```

En la expresión `setOther` le estoy pasando como referencia el objeto *php* ¿Por qué al realizar el `getOther` no se produce un null pointer?

Ambos objetos tienen la misma referencia de memoria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las variables funcionan como contenedores que almacenan la dirección en memoria de un objeto (una referencia).

En tu ejemplo la variable `php` guarda la referencia al objeto creado con `new Exam("PHP")`. Luego se le pasa la referencia a la función `setOther`, importante notar que lo que se pasa es el contenido de la variable `php` o sea la dirección en memoria. En este punto hay dos variables que guardan la misma referencia: `php` y `other`.

En la instrucción `php = null`, se limpia el contenido de la variable `php` pero no se está modificando la referencia al objeto en memoria. Esa referencia se encuentra guardada en la variable `other`.

Por esa razón `getOther` no produce un error.

Comment: Es decir, no se produce un NPE exactamente por el mismo motivo que se producen los *memory leak*, cuando cambias una variable a `null` solo estás cambiando la referencia a la que apunta esa variable, y no afecta a lo que haya guardado en memoria. Para que un objeto sea "eliminado" debe haber 0 referencias suyas almacenadas.

Answer (score 0):

NOTA: Publico esto como una respuesta por no poder publicar comentarios, pero creo que hay un punto que merece la pena aclarar.

En el código indicado jamás se va a producir una NPE al llamar a getOther, indistintamente de qué contenga el campo "other" del objeto *java*. En un caso se obtendrá un objeto concreto de la clase Exam y en el otro un null.

A mayores de eso tampoco se producirá un NPE por llamar a println con un null, tan sólo imprimirá "null" en consola.

El único cambio que podría provocar una NPE en ese código es hacer que la referencia contenida en el objeto *java* sea null (java = null).

Comment: En realidad, no es necesaria tu aclaración, porque tu respuesta efectivamente es una respuesta :)